# Second word completion with python

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, supervised-learning, completion

I'm new to machine learning and I'm trying to come up with a model that will complete all second words in phrases. I couldn't find solution to this exact problem although there are lots of tutorials on generating text with RNN.

So, consider you have the 2 following files:

1) a word dictionary for training

Say we have a table with 2 columns of word pairs: 'complete' and 'sample' such that the first column includes different word pairs ("Hello dear", "my name", "What time", "He goes", etc.) and the second one includes first words and only a part (> 2 letters) of second words ("Hello de", "my nam", "What ti", "He goe", etc.).

2) a table for testing

It's a table that consists of only 'sample' column.

The aim is to add 'complete' column to the second table with complete pairs of words.

I came up with the only way to do this:

1. compute the frequences of all first words (P(w1))
2. compute the frequences of all complete second words (P(w2))
3. compute the frequences of all first words given complete second words (P(w1|w2))
4. predict complete second words using Bayes rule:
   w2 = argmax_{w2} ( P(w2|w1)) = argmax_{w2} (P(w1|w2) * P(w2))
5. for each w1 in the test table w2 is the most probable w2 or the most frequent w2 (if w1 is not in the dict).

The problem is this algorithm doesn't work sufficiently well. How can I somehow optimise the probabilities (maybe gradient descent might be helpful?)? Is there any other way to address this task?

Comment: How do you measure a quality of your model, which metric is used?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please *do* take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that SO is *not* a system or code design service.

Comment: @MikhailStepanov the accuracy of the predictions for the second table

Comment: @Somestudent I guess perplexity not a most suitable metric for measuring word prediction qiality. Perplexity is better choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity and show more relevant metric. Anyway you may get a low metric just because you have a high-entropy data, i.e. diffferent words followed by the same words and visa versa

Comment: @MikhailStepanov yes it may be the case. But anyway, is there any way to optimise probabilities? For instance, I heard about gradient descent but I'm not sure it is useful in this case.
Or may be I should use other decision rule (not MAP) for class prediction?

Comment: @Somestudent ayway you'll reach some limit defined by enropy, and there's no possibility to overcome it without additional clearer data. Also, one of perplexity advantajes - it's just 2 in power of entropy of your data.  When I said entropy I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory). In your case I guess you've reach the limit already, try to check entropy of data and perplexity

Comment: @MikhailStepanov I know that I haven't reach the limit because there are competitors that have higher accuracy score :)

Comment: @Somestudent that case it's simpler to deal with data and code, at least with critical parts. Because it's hard to propose specific method without addidional information

Comment: @MikhailStepanov ok, I see. But supposing you had to develop an algorithm for this task which one would you choose?

Comment: @Somestudent guess I'll use the same approach as you (i.e. Bayes), but for "training" instead of words w1 and w2 - w1 concatenated with "known" part of w2, and predicting probability of specific "postfix" (unknown part) selected from all possible postfixes. As far as I understand, you're using only firsrt word, known part of second word will add more information, and classifier will fit better